# jQuery / Bootstrap: Child DIV opens up Parent Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have nested DIVs and a simple version can be shown like this:

```js
 $('#parent').click(function() {
  $('.parent').modal('show');
});
    
$('#child').click(function() {
  $('.parent').modal('hide'); // Added to try and hide
  $('.child').modal('show');
  $('.parent').modal('hide'); // Added to try and hide
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
  </div>
 </div>
```

The thing is when I click on the child div, the parent dialog also shows up behind the child dialog.

Any way to get around this?

Comment: Does e.preventDefault() `$('#child').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); //do others);` helps you?

Comment: Unfortunately not no

Answer (score 2):

It is happending because your child click event is bubbling up to the parent. Use `e.stopPropogation()` for the child div. This will prevent your click event from propogating to the parent.

```js
$('#parent').click(function() {
  $('.parent').modal('show');
});
    
$('#child').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropogation();
  $('.parent').modal('hide'); // Added to try and hide
  $('.child').modal('show');
  $('.parent').modal('hide'); // Added to try and hide
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Found out that was what I needed but I'll accept your answer thank you!

Comment: I did not. I couldn't do it at the time but I'll wait a little longer now.

Answer (score 0):

You can deal with such cases easily by mentioning the target in an attribute like below.

```
$('#parent, #child').click(function() {
   var target = $(this).data('target');
   $('.'+target).modal('show');
   // write code to hide others if necessary
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent" data-target="parent">
  <div id="child" data-target="child">
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this before showing the modal:

```
 $( '.modal' ).remove();
$( '.child' ).modal('show');
```

Remove the modal before using show. Hope this will fix your issue