# Cancel onClick event of parent component in child component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that looks like:

```
<ParentComponent onClick={this.doSomething}>
  <ChildComponent onClick={this.doSomethingElse} />
</Parent>
```

If I click on the ChildComponent, both doSomethingElse and doSomething fire. How can I cancel the parent component onClick event propagation when the child onClick event fires?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery / Bootstrap: Child DIV opens up Parent Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40106573/jquery-bootstrap-child-div-opens-up-parent-modal)

Comment: No it's not even a little bit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should add the line `e.stopPropagation();` to the top of your `this.doSomethingElse` event handler.

[Event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

> Prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases.

So when you use `e.StopPropagation()` in an event handler it prevents the event from bubbling up to ancestors and triggering their event handlers.

Make sure to include `e` as an argument of your `this.doSomethingElse` method.

```
doSomethingElse( e ) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  // ... do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to avoid duplicating events, use `stopPropagation` function.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  
  firstHandle = () => {
    console.log('parent');
  }
  
  secondHandle = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('child');
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.firstHandle}>
        Parent
        <div onClick={this.secondHandle}>child</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```